# Polymer 2.0 call child event from parent

Tags: javascript, polymer

I keep running into bad examples or outdated 1.0 docs regarding calling child event from the parent in Polymer 2.0.  Essentially all I want to accomplish is triggering a child event from the parent.  But I also can not seem to find a reference in the tree structure of the parent element as well when call "this".

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="import" href="/elements/parent-element.html">
</head>
<body>
    <parent-element></parent-element>
    <script src="js/polymer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**parent-element.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="./child-element.html">
<dom-module id="parent-element">

  <template>
    <div>
      parent
      <child-element></child-element>
     </div>
  </template>

  <script>
    class ParentElement extends Polymer.Element {
        constructor(){
            super()

        }

      callChildEvent(){
        // call event
      }

        static get is() { 
            return "parent-element"; 
        }
    }
    customElements.define(ParentElement.is, ParentElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

**child-element.html**

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="child-element">
  <template>
    <div on-click="customEvent">
        child element
    </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    class ChildElement extends Polymer.Element {
        constructor(){
            super()
        }

        childEvent(){
            console.log('event fired');
        }

        static get is() { 
            return "child-element"; 
        }
    }
    customElements.define(ChildElement.is, ChildElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give an id to

```
<child-element id="childEl"></child-element>
```

And fire child element function at parent like:

```
this.$.childEl.childEvent();
```

Comment: Maybe you might be able to help with the reverse side of things as well?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820353/polymer-2-0-access-a-parent-component-from-child-component

Answer (score 1):

This is how my template of polymer 3.0 component looks like.

```
 static get template() {
     return html`
       <my-component id="myComponent" />
     `
 }
```

And now to call any method in my component class, I do it like this.

```
  this.$.myComponent.myMethod();
```

Here `myComponent` after `$` is the `id` of `my-component`.

Comment: Any specific reason for downvoting it works perfect in my code.