# Polymer 2.0 access a parent component from child component

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a nested component, what is the Polymer way to travel up the DOM or component tree in this case.

```
<parent-component>
  <some-component>
    <component-i-am-starting-from></<component-i-am-starting-from>
  </some-component>
 <some-other-component>
 </some-other-component>
</parent-component>
```

I'd like to be at a deep nested component and reference any of the parent components and their models or trigger an event inside one of them. Bonus if I can access sibling components, etc.

Traveling down was easy enough with

```
this.$.idOfChildComponent.event()
```

I have tried dispatchEvent, domHost, shadowRoot, can't seem to get any further up the component tree then the direct parent or get an error back that something is undefined, is not a function, etc.

Is there a way like React to pass a reference down as a property. The docs do not seem to be helpful nor scouring the internet.

Thanks!

**update**

So I am not sure if this is the correct way but it works ok calling a parent function from a child function.

```
<parent-component id="parentComponent">
  <some-component>
    <component-i-am-starting-from></<component-i-am-starting-from>
  </some-component>
 <some-other-component>
 </some-other-component>
</parent-component>

componentIAmStartingFromFunc(){
 document.getElementById('parentElement').parentElementFunc()
}
```

However does not seem to work for siblings?

** Update ** 
I essentially did the same the to call the sibling event by calling the parent from one of its children, and then sent out a trigger to the sibling which is also a child component.

Comment: Hope below answer fits your need. In case please let me know, if you need more.

Answer (score 2):

Calling a parent function from child ;

**child-component.html (polymer 2.x)**

```
this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('upway-func', {detail: {op:"Optionally I can send some data"}}));
```

**child-component.html (polymer 1.x)**

```
 this.fire('upway-func', {detail: {op:"Optionally I can send some data"}});
```

**parent-component.html**

```
...
<child-component on-upway-func='_someFunction'></child-component>

...
_someFunction(d){
  console.log(d.detail.op); // "Optionally I can send some data"
 }
```

Here [this link](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events#custom-events) for more detail

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `this.parentElement`?

Ask yourself: if I were a `span` in a `div`, how would I get to the `div`?

If you want to find a particular element in the ancestor chain by selector, you can use `.closest()` in good browsers or https://github.com/jonathantneal/closest

The message system mentioned in another answer can work but doesn't help you with positional relationship traversing which I assume your question was requiring. Passing ids and/or objects down can be used with messages in some cases.

Comment: Right I understand I can move up the node tree in plain Javascript, but I am assuming there is a Polymer way to reference components.  The last thing I want to do from a deep nested component is "this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement". Seems like a hack and I can't imagine the Polymer team intended that...

Comment: I don't think Polymer targets use cases that involve this kind of upward structural dependency binding.