# Global functions in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Is there any way to declare a global function in Polymer 2.0 that can be used in other components? I have a `moment.html` file for using moment.js in the project:

```js
<script src="../bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
```

In the same file I also declare a function instead of declaring it in every single component where I want to use it:

```js
<script>
  function format(date) {
    return moment(date).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY');
  }
</script>
```

The `moment` object is available after importing the file but when I try to call the `format` function it gives me the warning `method 'format' not defined`. How can I make the function publicly available?

**Edit**: I can call the `format` function from within the script tags of another component, but I cannot access it from within a template, i.e. with:

```html
<strong>[[format(event.date)]]</strong>
```

I want to render the result from the function on the page, not access it programmatically.

Comment: I have tested this. and working good at my own side, just try to change `format(date) {..` to `myFormat(data) {..` etc. to see which format function gives `'format' not defined` .. I mean `myFormat` or `moment(date).format(..`.  Also consider to call `myFormat` function with `this.myFormat(date)` ,

Comment: Oh, you're right, the function is accessible from within the script tags of another component. However, I'm trying to call it from within a template. I updated my question.

Comment: It is the same, below I called the function with a button in a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, for your task, the best documentation is Monica Dinculescu's own cheat sheet.

https://meowni.ca/posts/polymer-2-cheatsheet/#defining-a-mixin

She's a Polymer developer. Below is me copy pasting from the link. It's the `extends MyMixin(Polymer.Element)` that does the magic.

---

Defining a class expression mixin to share implementation between different elements:

```
<script>
  MyMixin = function(superClass) {
    return class extends superClass {
      // Code that you want common to elements.
      // If you're going to override a lifecycle method, remember that a) you
      // might need to call super but b) it might not exist
      connectedCallback() {
        if (super.connectedCallback) {
          super.connectedCallback();
        }
        /* ... */
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Using the mixin in an element definition:

```
<dom-module id="element-name">
  <template><!-- ... --></template>
  <script>
    // This could also be a sequence:
    //class MyElement extends AnotherMixin(MyMixin(Polymer.Element)) { … }
    class MyElement extends MyMixin(Polymer.Element) {
      static get is() { return 'element-name' }
      /* ... */
    }
    customElements.define(MyElement.is, MyElement);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks promising. I'll try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample how I work it ;

```
<paper-button on-tap="customfunc"> Test </paper-button>
<div><strong>[[format(date)]]</strong></div>   // result at screen: Saturday, 20 January 2018
  ...
<script>
class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'test-component'; }

  ready(){
      super.ready();
      this.set('date', new Date())
   }
   customfunc() {
      var d = new Date();
      var dd = this.format(d);
      console.log("d ", d, " - dd = ", dd);// d  Sat Jan 20 2018 17:02:38 GMT+0300 (Türkiye Standart Saati)  - dd =  Saturday, 20 January 2018
   }
   format(date){
      return moment(date).format('dddd, D MMMM YYYY');
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer but 1) The `format` function should be defined in another file and 2) It should be called directly from the template, not from within the script tags. I want to render the result from `format` on the page.

Comment: Well, the other file is a child of this element or parent element. There are Polymer ways to call functions between each elements. Beside, it is the same with calling `[[format(event.date)]]`, I will update my answer upon I get information.

Comment: @yberg, I updated the code, how it calls from the template. Also. just for information, also check this link to invoke functions between elements: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47820353/polymer-2-0-access-a-parent-component-from-child-component/47825236#47825236

Answer (score 0):

As Your `format_function` is in shadow root, you have to use `.shadowRoot.querySelector`

below is my working code, in this i have `format_funtion` in `page1` and am calling it in `page2`

```html
<script src="https://polygit.org/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/components/polymer/polymer-element.html">


<!-- my-app element -->
<dom-module id="my-app">
  <template>   
    <my-page1></my-page1>
    <my-page2></my-page2> 
  </template>
  <script>
    class MyApp extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-app'
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyApp.is, MyApp);
  </script>
</dom-module>


<!-- page1 element -->
<dom-module id="my-page1">
  <script>
    class MyPage1 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {
        return 'my-page1';
      }
      constructor() {
        super();
      }
      format_function() {
        alert("in format function");
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage1.is, MyPage1);
  </script>
</dom-module>

<!-- page2 element -->
<dom-module id="my-page2">
  <template> <div on-click="test">click to test format_funtion.....!</div></template>
  <script>
    class MyPage2 extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {return 'my-page2';}
      
      test() {
        var host = document.querySelector('my-app').shadowRoot.querySelector('my-page1');
        host. format_function();
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define(MyPage2.is, MyPage2);
  </script>
</dom-module>



<!-- calling element -->
<my-app></my-app>
```

> Don't forget to import files e.g `page.html` or `page2.html`